# Unable to see pie chart in template using django and chart js

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, chart.js

**I want to count the number of companies in companytype model and show that in pie chart. The count should by the name field in company table.**

> eg: If Company Type is medical and there are 4 companies in that category then i want to show its count on pie chart.

**models.py**

```
class CompanyType(models.Model):
    company_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    company_type = models.ForeignKey(CompanyType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    labels = []
    data = []
                               
    queryset = Company.objects.values('company_type__company_type').annotate(company_type_sum=Count('name')).order_by('-company_type_sum')
    for entry in queryset:
        labels.append(entry['company_type__company_type'])
        data.append(entry['company_type_sum'])


    context = {
        'labels':labels,
        'data':data,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

**I have taken Chartjs code from index.html file if there is something wrong.**

**index.html**

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: [data.labels],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Companies in Particular Section',
            data: [data.data],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your data in arrays in your `views.py` but then also make it an array in your `new Chart`, this 2D array is not being liked by chart.js, changing your `new Chart` to this should fix the issue:

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: data.labels, // Remove double array
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Companies in Particular Section',
      data: data.data, // Remove double array
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
  }
});
```

On a side note, the pie chart does not have a y scale so you will get ugly lines behind your pie if you keep it in your options, removing it will make your chart look a lot better

Comment: I tried removing the brackets still not working.

Comment: Do you actually have a canvas tag in your html with the ID of `myChart`?

Comment: Yes there is ID written in canvas tag.